# Using Qt to configure OpenCV library failed

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opencv, qt-creator

I'm new to Qt creator. Yesterday, I followed the official instructions to configure OpenCV library but it failed. I tried everything on the Internet but it just didn't work. Detailed are listed as belows:
test code is simple, I only want to ensure whether the library works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My project configuration is like below :

[image]

I thought there might be a problem in debugger. I configure the debugger and I'm quite sure it's ok. The picture is here:

[image]

But it just doesn't work. When I click build and run, it says:

> C1083: cannot open containing files: "opencv2/opencv.hpp": No such
>   file or directory.

What's strange is when I include `<files>` in the editor, the automatic code completion can detect the existence of the OpenCV library and hint after `<opencv2/>` that there are opencv.hpp, core.hpp .etc. and in the Include Hierarchy, the opencv.hpp exists.

So what might be the problem?

Comment: I guess you are on Linux, have you installed all required dev packages? Like `libopencv-dev`. Or are you compiling opencv?

Comment: @CsabaToth sorry to forget the platform. it's on windows. besides, I use the vc2012 runtime, the sources are compiled already in \ build directory.

Comment: So you can actually find `opencv.hpp` in the file system? Then you need to set some environment variable or settings in Qt creator to point to OpenCV source's location. Are you following an actual tutorial?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I try and try and finally it works. I think the problem might be the clash between x64 and x86. I redefine the build and run kit, making every file work on platform x64 and it works. To conclude, there're 3 points I should note. First, the "path" environment variables of opencv library. second, WDK should be downloaded and installed to support the debug on windows platform, not the gdb. And third, appropriate libraries is chosen to work on specific platform of different bit.